# Execute Three Distinct Functions in for loop with delays

Tags: javascript, for-loop, arguments, settimeout, delay

Say I have three functions that I want to run in sequence 5 times waiting one second between each one and the first one takes the variable in the for loop as an argument. Something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       one(i);
   },1000);
   setTimeout(function(){
       two();
   },2000);
   setTimeout(function(){
       three();
   },3000);
}
```

I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: One approach would be to call function `two()` from with a timeout within function `one()`, and function `three()` with a timeout from within function `two()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout()` sets up a timer to run a function in the future but returns immediately, so your function will run `one()` 5 times after 1 second, `two()` 5 times after 2 seconds and `three()` 5 times after 3 seconds.

You could achieve your goal with

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       one(i);
   },(i * 3 + 1) * 1000);
   setTimeout(function(){
       two();
   },(i * 3 + 2) * 1000);
   setTimeout(function(){
       three();
   },(i * 3 + 3) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Can you explain to me just how you set up the intervals so that I can understand it better? Thank you so much

Comment: All the events are set up immediately, so all the events are relative to the start time.  If we ignore the `* 1000` (which is just converting ms into seconds), we are just setting to the to (i * 3) (ie 3 seconds for each of the 5 loops) plus 1, 2 or 3 seconds for functions one(), two() and three()